# Don't see UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

My application starts with Root controller called `TaskController : UINavigationController` as as root view controller of `UINavigationController` i created class 
`TaskRootController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate>` (it has add as view UITableView); When I start application i see only Title form TaskRootController and background color from it. But I don't see table view. If my application starts with TaskRootController as a rootViewController I see table view.

How can I make to see table view in may case ?
PS. Even if I switch TaskRootController to TaskRootController : UITableViewController the behavior is the same. 
my code is below:

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize taskController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.taskController = [TaskController alloc];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.taskController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

@end
```

TaskController.m

```
@implementation TaskController

@synthesize taskRootController;

- (void) pushInboxController
{
    TaskBoxController *taskBoxController = [[TaskBoxController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
    [self pushViewController:taskBoxController animated:YES];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        [self.navigationBar setBarStyle: UIBarStyleBlack];
        [self.navigationBar setTranslucent: NO];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.taskRootController = [[TaskRootController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
    UIViewController *root = self.taskRootController;
    [self initWithRootViewController: root];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(pushInboxController)];
}

@end
```

TaskRootController.m

```
@implementation TaskRootController

@synthesize taskRootView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"DUPA");

    NSLog(@"SIZE x:%f,y:%f ; %f:%f", self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.title = @"Root";
    self.taskRootView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.taskRootView.delegate = self;
    self.taskRootView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.taskRootView];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1; // put number for section.
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 6; // put number as you want row in section.
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat result = 20.0f;
    if([tableView isEqual:self.taskRootView])
    {
        result = 40.0f;
    }
    return result;
}

@end
```

Comment: Why did you take nib name as "nil" in this     self.taskRootController = [[TaskRootController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];

Comment: because i don't have xib file

Comment: ok, then try to assign taskController like this  self.taskController = [[TaskController alloc]init];  instead of  self.taskController = [TaskController alloc];

Answer (score 1):

Add this delegate method .

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"this is row";

    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT :**

put `init` at when you create object of `TaskController` in **`AppDelegate.m`**

```
self.taskController = [[TaskController alloc]init];
```

And also put both delegate and datasource to `TaskController.h`

```
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

and add its relavent methods.

Comment: I add this method to TaskRootController which contains table view and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate

```
     self.taskController = [[TaskController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TaskController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     UINavigationController *task = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.taskController];

    self.window.rootViewController = task;
```

In your TaskController

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
       {
         [super viewDidLoad];
         TaskRootController *tc = [[TaskRootController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TaskRootController" bundle:[NSBundle mainbundle]];
        [self addChildViewController:tc];
        [tc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self.view addSubview:tc.view];
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

set delegate and datasource of your tableview

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [yourArray count];

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"row";
    return cell;
}
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
in Appdelegate File :-

self.TaskViewController = [[TaskViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TaskViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.TaskViewController];

[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];//ios-6
                           or
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];//<ios-6

Add a Delegate Method in UITableViewDelagates:-

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Name";

    return cell;
}
```